# Casting IEnumerable to IList returns null

Tags: c#, linq

I'm calling my repo with a code that returns an

```
IEnumerable<MyEntity>
```

And when I try to materialize the result it only works if I do .ToList() on the result, but if I try a

```
as IList<MyEntity>
```

It gives null. Shouldn't they produce the same result?

Comment: `ToList` is a method that enumerates the whole sequence and adds each item to a new list, whereas `as IList<T>` is just casting the enumerable to the desired type which of course will fails because it **is not** an `IList<T>` but just a query.

Comment: Note that the as operator performs only reference conversions, nullable conversions, and boxing conversions. The as operator can't perform other conversions, such as user-defined conversions, which should instead be performed by using cast expressions.

Comment: While `ToList` converts the source into a `List`, hence the data retrieval, as `IList` will fail if the source is not an `IList`. If you want to materialize the result you should call any method that has a `To[whatever]` to force the retrieval.

Comment: these comments and most of the answers are correct; what is your actual `IEnumerable<MyEntity>` `Type` here, `HashSet` or `DbSet`?  try `as ISet<MyEntity>` in place of `as IList<MyEntity>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then your enumerable wasn't of a type that implements `IList<T>`, like `List<T>` or similar. `as` just casts the variable to the specified type if the instance is of that type. It doesn't make any conversion.

`ToList()` actually force creation of a new `List<T>`, so it is logical that the new instance created there does implement `IList<T>`.

Answer (score 4):

`.ToList()` converts your `IEnumerable` to `List`.
`as IList` ("tries to") cast your `IEnumerable` to `IList`.

There is a chance that your `IEnumerable` isn't an `IList` at all, a simple example could be `class Dictionary`:

```
public class Dictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, 
    ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, 
    IEnumerable, IDictionary, ICollection, IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>, 
    IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, ISerializable, 
    IDeserializationCallback
```

We can see that none of the above interfaces is an `IList`.
**Edit:** thanks to [@patrick-hofman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50579524/casting-ienumerable-to-ilist-returns-null/50579618#comment88168755_50579618) comment, it is important to [check](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt472912(v=vs.110).aspx) the whole chain of implementations in order to be sure that this class isn't an `IList`(which of course ok in that case).

That said, as we can see from `IList` signature:

```
public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
```

`IList` is an `IEnumerable`, but `IEnumerable` is not an `IList`.

Comment: It is a simple example of why such cast might not work.

Comment: Unless you show every interface definition of the dictionary, your code says nothing. How can you know from that code that `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` doesn't implement `IList<T>`?

Comment: You are right, the bare signature itself doesn't necessarily tell it is not an IList. I'll edit the answer to emphasize it. thanks.

Comment: @Yan I think the answer might be better without the Dictionary signature, odds are someone googling for this question is likely to be at a level where a 2 parameter generic signature that implements 10 interfaces will confuse more than it will help them. Simply saying not all collections implement IList and not all IEnumerable are even materialized collections would help more i think.